# Assigning a scalar variable from sp_executesql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need anyone's help. I am trying to assign a scalar variable from a query, running from sp_executesql. my query is below:

```
select @sql = N'Select @found = count(' +@column+ ') from ' +@table+ ' where 
                +@column+ ' = ''' +@intVariable+''';';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, N'@table nvarchar(max), @column nvarchar(max), 
               @temp_id nvarchar(max), @found int', 
               @table,@column,@temp_id,@found;
```

The query does not yield any errors. but @found was not assigned the result of the query. I tried to change to set but also the same. can anyone please tell me what is wrong with the query? I have been doing this for all day long.

Thanks so much in advance for all the help i can get.

Answer (score 2):

Your script would look as follows:

```
DECLARE @found int;

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
    N'Select @found = count(' +QUOTENAME(@column)+ ') '+
    N'from ' +QUOTENAME(@table)+ ' '+
    N'where ' +QUOTENAME(@column)+ '=@intVariable;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, '@intVariable INT, @found INT OUTPUT', @intVariable, @found OUTPUT;
```

This has `@found` as an OUTPUT variable. It is necessary to specify this both in the parameter string and when passing the parameter to `sp_executesql` to output the value.

Also, QUOTENAME() is used to properly escape object names.